# How to find the probability between two jobs given only standard deviation and mean?

Tags: probability, normal-distribution, cumulative-distribution-functions

I'm aware, for a standard normal distribution using $Z$ score, we can find the probability $Pr(x<a)$.

However, how to solve a problem as follows?

There are two jobs, the industrial job with the mean salary of 60,000 and standard deviation of 5,000 and another traveling job with the mean salary of 45,000 and standard deviation of 35,000.

What is the probability that traveling job is better than industrial job?

Thanks.

Comment: There appears to be missing some information from your problem. With that info alone, it is impossible to calculate. Where is this problem from? and what have you done?.

Comment: Do you know what the distribution of the difference of two normal random variables looks like? If you let $X\sim \mathscr{N} (60000, 5000)$ and $Y\sim \mathscr{N} (45000, 35000)$, what does the distribution of $Z = X- Y$ look like?

Comment: Normal distribution.

Comment: @WangYeFei, this is from EZ Stats by Barrons on normal distribution chapter.

Comment: Yes, the difference is normal. What does that difference represent? You can use that to answer the question - there's no information missing here, as long as we're treating the two jobs as independent.

Comment: Do I solve using the following expression? https://mathworld.wolfram.com/NormalDifferenceDistribution.html

Comment: Kind of. Can you edit your question to include any work you can do to determine the distribution of the difference?